# How to sort the list if IP address fetched using Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am fetching the list of IP addresses of an adapter using Win32NetworkAdapterConfiguration:

```
$ip= $ip=Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
select IPAddress
```

The list of IP addresses comes as:

```
{192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.9, 192.168.1.8.....}
```

is there an easy way to sort this list in ascending order?
I need the out put like:

```
{192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3.....}
```

Comment: `$ip=Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select -Expand IPAddress |  Sort`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code should work. You can sort objects by `Sort-Object`

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Sort-Object IPAddress | select IPAddress
```

**Edit:**

Since you are getting all those IPs from the same adapter the curly braces `{}` turn it into an object powershell is struggling to sort. Back to arrays!

```
$ip = {192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.9, 192.168.1.8, 192.168.1.1}  
$ip =$ip.ToString()
$a= $ip.Split(",")
$a | sort
```

You will have to filter out mac addresses: create a new array with only ips:

```
$new=for ($i=0;$i -lt $array.count;$i+=2) {$a[$i]}
```

So, this should work:

```
$ip= $ip=Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | select IPAddress
$ip =$ip.ToString()
$a= $ip.Split(",")
$new=for ($i=0;$i -lt $array.count;$i+=2) {$a[$i]}
$new | sort
```

Comment: I tried Sort-Object but that does not seem to help, i am still seeing the IP addresses in same order

Comment: Remove the `-Decending` part.

`Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Sort-Object IPAddress | select IPAddress`

Comment: Sort-Object IPAddress 
or
Sort-Object IPAddress -Descending

both are giving the same result, Sort-Object does not seem to take effect on this

Comment: Please note, I am not trying to sort  IP lists from multiple adapters as shown in your screen shot.

I am trying to sort the list of IP address from a single adapter as I have mentioned in my main post:

The output which is coming as following:

{192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.9, 192.168.1.8.... 192.168.1.1}

needs to come as :

{192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3.... 192.168.1.10}